# how to perform multiple splits in one line?

Tags: python

I have a string in the following format:
`x = "key1:value1 key2:value2 key3:value3"`
How to write a one-line python command to have at the end a list of dictionaries with:

```
[
   {'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'},
   {'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'},
   {'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'}
]
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why does it have to be in one line?

Comment: there is no special reason, you can ask the same question for every one line operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single line python function to do this :

```py
to_dict = lambda string: [{"key": k, "value": v} for k, v in (s.split(":") for s in string.split())]
```

Example use :

```py
x = "key1:value1 key2:value2 key3:value3"
to_dict = lambda string: [{"key": k, "value": v} for k, v in (s.split(":") for s in string.split())]

print(to_dict(x))
# [{'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}, 
# {'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'}, 
# {'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use python `string split()`

```
[{'key':x.split(':')[0], 'value':x.split(':')[1]} for x in x.split()]
```

which gives you expected output in the list form

```
[
    {'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}, 
    {'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'}, 
    {'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'}
]
```

Comment: the drawback of this is the execution of the same split twice (`x.split(':')`)